# Mongoose: create multiple documents if filter finds none

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to create multiple documents based on a filter: if document not found => create it.

After searching a bit I found that the correct way to do so is by using `updateMany` and setting `upsert: true` ([docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateMany/#update-multiple-documents-with-upsert)).

This made somewhat sense from the documentation's example but as I understand it the `filter` modifier would be used for the newly-created document. As in the example:

```
try {
    db.inspectors.updateMany(
        { "Sector" : { $gt : 4 }, "inspector" : "R. Coltrane" },
        { $set: { "Patrolling" : false } },
        { upsert: true }
    );
} catch (e) {
    print(e);
}
```

`"Inspector" : "R. Coltrane"` would be inserted to the newly-created document.

But what if my `setOnInsert` modifier contains the same field as the one in the `filter`?

What my code looks like:

```
//first find the already-created tags
await tagModel.find({"tagName": tags}).select('tagName -_id').exec()
    .then(async (result: Tag[])=>{
    //create the new tags
    const newTags = tags.map((tag: any)=>new tagModel({tagName: tag}));
    //now insert only the new tags, filtering out the already-created tags ("result")
    await tagModel.updateMany(
               {"tagName": result}, 
               {$setOnInsert: newTags} ,
               {upsert: true},
               (err:any, res:any)=>{
               ...
```

At first, `result` is an empty Array (`[]`). What is created in my MongoDB database is a new `Tag` document, but its `tagName` is the `result` object. Meaning, it looks like:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "61659c92c6267fe11963b236"
    },
    "tagName": {
        "$in": []
    }
}
```

So essentially my question is, what am I suppose to do in this case where my `update` modifier should replace my `filter` query? Perhaps it's just something bad in my code that makes the `updateMany` function to malfunction? Or should I replace it with a different function?

Comment: Note: `newTags` object contains the fields `tagName` and `_id`.

Comment: For now I've replaced this code with `initializeUnorderedBulkOp` and `bulk.insert()` which ignores duplicates (I've also unique'd `tagName` for it to work). But I still want to understand how I can achieve the same goal with `updateMany`, thinking it'd be more efficient than bulk insertion (could be wrong though).